# how to get access token refreshed from facebook?

Tags: c#

As i am new to .Net, i am facing few problems with facebook on which i am working now .
hello every one here , i am using this code to access facebook friends information.
here i am taking access token from facebook manually.
for that i need to login every time to facebook which i don't want here.
i want my access token to be refreshed when i run my application.
is there any way to do this.
please , help me out here

```
enter code here
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   String strAccessToken ="";
   var client = new FacebookClient(strAccessToken);
   var result = client.Get("me/friends");

}
```